# How to send 20K+ push notifications in iOS using PHP

Tags: php, ios, push-notification

The following code works, but it sends only around 1000 push notifications after the timeout of 5 minutes, I have set `ini_set('max_execution_time', 30000);` but not working also set in PHP.ini file

```
function iphone_push(device<sub>token</sub>, message = "", title = "", badge = 1)
{
    try {
        $write_data = "";
        $streamContext = stream_context_create();
        stream_context_set_option($streamContext, 'ssl', 'local_cert', $this->certificate_path);
        $push_arr = array(
            "alert" => $title,
            "sound" => "push_sound.wav",
            "badge" => 1,
        );
        $payload = array();
        $payload['aps'] = $push_arr;
        $payload = json_encode($payload);
        for ($i = 0; $i < count($device_token); $i++)
        {
           $fp = stream_socket_client($this->apns_host, $error, $errorString, 60, STREAM_CLIENT_CONNECT, $streamContext);
           if ($device_token[$i] == "")
                continue;
            $apnsMessage = chr(0) . Chr(0) . Chr(32) . Pack('H*', str_replace(' ', '', $device_token[$i])) . Chr(0) . Chr(strlen($payload)) . $payload;
            fwrite($fp, $apnsMessage);
        }
        fclose($fp);
    } catch (Exception $e) {
        write_log("ipush", $e->getMessage());
    }
    return success_res("iphone_push_sent");
}
```

Comment: Have you tried `set_time_limit(0);`?

Comment: Are the push notifications time sensitive? If so you might want to start sending from multiple server is batches. Sending in batches is also a good idea if you need to send lots of pus notifications.

Comment: Hi i have set set_time_limit(0); but same error occur

Comment: Hi @rckoenes  its good idea but its my client project so Its take more expanse for purchase multiple server.